# java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: running pyspark on AWS

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, hdfs, pyspark

I am using AWS for the first time and I have stored my file on AWS. This is what I have tried using to read the file so far.

```
artist_data = sc.textFile('hdfs:///<aws_server>:<port>/home/ubuntu/artist_stuff/_artist_data')
```

also tried:

```
artist_data = sc.textFile('hdfs:////home/ubuntu/artist_stuff/_artist_data')
```

Then I just did made my RDD:

```
artist_data = artist_data.map(lambda line:line.encode("ascii", "ignore").strip().split()).filter(lambda line: len(line) > 1)
```

I get this error each time I run artist_data.collect().

When I just tried `sc.textFile("file:///home/ubuntu/artist_stuff/_artist_data")` I get a different error saying : InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/ubuntu/Assignment_2/_artist_data which I am guessing is an error due to partitions or something. Hence I chose to code it is as `hdfs:///`

Here is the complete error - log:

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
----> 1 artist_data.collect()
```

/home/ubuntu/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)

```
774         """
775         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
```

--> 776             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    777         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    778

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in **call**(self, *args)

```
  1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:
```

/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)

```
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.io.IOException: Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/home/ubuntu/artist_stuff/_artist_data
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Just edit your question if you need to add other details.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what else to add.

Comment: I meant whatever you put in comments.